# How to connect my Android app to my PHP/MySQL backend?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have two questions about the connection between Android and PHP/MySQL.

1. If I used version 3 and above is that true that I need to do the connection in background using a separate thread?
2. Is it necessary  to use JSON to get back the answers?

I wrote code without using multi-threading and JSON but it only works on the version of 2.3 and above. I tried on the 4.0 and 4.2, but it didn't give back any response.

Comment: android cannot talk to mysql, and you don't want it too - your database should never be directly exposed to the public network. android should talk to PHP, and php will talk to mysql.

Comment: yess i know that but what about the using of the thread and the json class ??

Comment: YES you do have to use AsyncTask(Thread) otherwise you will get a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Look out there are plenty of tuts out there

Comment: Android versions later that Honeycomb require that all network communications be done off the main thread. If you don't do this, then the app will throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your first question:**

Yes. *Always* do network tasks or anything else that takes time in the background. The best way to do this would be to use an `AsyncTask`. [This article](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) explains `AsyncTask` way better than I can, go read it.

Contrary to what the comments on your question say, the reason you should use a separate thread is not because you'd get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` otherwise. It's because it's a better practice and because it makes sure your app doesn't stutter while it does the network task. The main task also handles animations etc. in your `Activity`, so doing any task on the main thread for X time, means the app stutters for X time.

**Your second question:**

No, it isn't necessary to use JSON. You do want to route your requests through a script on your webpage though (whether that'd be PHP, Ruby, Python, whatever), instead of interfacing with your database directly. This way, you can restrict the actions your app is able to perform, as well as the actions a potential hacker is able to perform.

Like I said, it is not necessary to use JSON. However, it's the most widely accepted way to get information from your server to your app, for a couple of reasons. The most prevalent 2 being:

1. **Low overhead**: JSON uses very little 'extra' characters between your data, as opposed to, for example, XML, which has long tags, et cetera;
2. **Ease of use**: Android has JSON tools built in for you to leverage, which makes it very easy for you to work with JSON. For example, take this bit of JSON:

`[{'id':11,'name':'Bob'},{'id':42,'name':'Sally'}]`

To parse this in your Android app, you could do:

```
public List<Person> parseJson(String jsonString) {

    // Initialize the ArrayList we're gonna store the people in
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    try {
        // Convert the JSON from text (String) to a JSON Array, so we can
        // more easily traverse it
        JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

        // loop through the prople in the JSON Array
        for(int i=0; i<rootArray.length(); 

            // Get the object at position i from the JSON Array
            JSONObject workingObj = rootArray.get(i);

            // Do what you have to to store the data. In this example,
            // I'm using a class called 'Person' which has setters for Id and Name
            Person p = new Person();

            // Get all the info you need from the JSON Object. As you can see
            // in the JSON snippet, we have an integer with key 'id' and a
            // string with key 'name'
            p.setId(workingObj.getInt("id"));
            p.setName(workingObj.getString("name"));

            // add the Person p to the ArrayList
            people.add(p);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // properly handle all exceptions!
    }
    return people;
}
```

As you can see, all parsing is done for you, and you just have to accommodate for the data structure.